# Is it possible to classify or add attributes to the site collection (spsite) and subsite (spweb) objects?

Tags: managed-metadata

I have 5 site collections with 85 subsites. For each site collection I want to associate a **single** country value for all content. For each subsite I want to associate a **single** office ID for all content. I would like each piece of content in the parent containter to have that value associated with it. So anytime I add a new document or list item, it's always associated with the country and office ID of the parent container.

Business reasons for this are:

- Allow users to refine search results based off of country or office location.
- We have a number of aggregate pages that list content from the different site collections. We want the option to organize it by country or office location.

**Questions**

- Is it possible to classify or add attributes to the site collection
  (spsite) and subsite (spweb) objects?
- Is it possible the child objects (documents and list items) to inherit values set at the parent object level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SPWeb object has a property bag (i.e. a collection of name-value pairs) where you can store any values that you like. The SPSite does not have a property bag so people commonly store its property values in the root SPWeb.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.properties.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with Powershell. You would need to create a script that goes over all the necessary webs and sub-webs recursively and finding each list, and adding the column for each. It may be in your best interest to make a site column, then associate all the content with it using the lookup column.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm looking to see if its possible to set the value at the SPSite or SPWeb object and have all the list items inherit that value. I've update the question to better explain my original intent.